# Route53で取得したドメインでEC2インスタンスに名前解決できない

Tags: aws, amazon-route53

EC2で運用していく予定のWEBアプリにドメインを紐づけたいのですが、取得したドメインでアクセスできません。

以下は試した内容です。

- EIPでのアクセスは可能。
- Route53でホストゾーンを再作成し、[Amazon Registrar](https://registrar.amazon.com/whois)でName Serverを確認した上でレコードを変更した。
  ([Route 53 を DNS サービスとして使用している際に発生する NXDOMAIN レスポンスをトラブルシューティングするにはどうすればよいですか?](https://repost.aws/ja/knowledge-center/route-53-troubleshoot-nxdomain-responses)より、「ネームサーバーが同一でない場合は、ドメインレジストラでネームサーバーを更新する必要があります。ドメインが Route 53 に登録されている場合は、「ドメインのネームサーバーおよびグルーレコードの追加あるいは変更」を参照してください」の記述を読んで、レコードを変更しました)
- VPCホストの「ドメイン名」「DNS解決」を「有効」に変更した。
- digでは　status: SERVFAIL　が返ってくる
- nslookupでは　server can't find ドメイン: NXDOMAIN　が返ってくる

知見が浅いため、この他必要な情報があればお伝えいたします。

---

参考にした記事

- [Route53でホストゾーン作成時にSERVFAILとなる](https://qiita.com/kaikusakari/items/628fa099d25392e7e7db)
- [Route53で取得したドメインでアクセスしてみよう](https://note.com/standenglish/n/n8f18cb21ac3d#23a9389d-108a-4e0d-9b81-80c0c89803bd)
- [DNS 設定を変更したが、変更が適用されていない](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/troubleshooting-new-dns-settings-not-in-effect.html)

Comment: 「Amazon RegistrarでName Serverを確認した」辺りが適切でない予感がします。何をどう確認したのか、具体的に記述してください。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。

以下の記事を参考にして確認したところ、
route53で設定されているネームサーバーと異なっていることに気づきました。

そこで、同記事の
`「whois の出力を参照し、自身のドメインに対する権威ネームサーバーを書き留めます。」`より、
[Amazon Registerのwhois検索ツール](https://registrar.amazon.com/whois) から表示されたネームサーバーを書き留めました。

次に、

`「ネームサーバーが同一でない場合は、ドメインレジストラでネームサーバーを更新する必要があります。ドメインが Route 53 に登録されている場合は、「ドメインのネームサーバーおよびグルーレコードの追加あるいは変更」を参照してください」`より、
ホストゾーンの詳細　からネームサーバーの書き換えを行いました。

参考
[Route 53 を DNS サービスとして使用している際に発生する NXDOMAIN レスポンスをトラブルシューティングするにはどうすればよいですか?](https://repost.aws/ja/knowledge-center/route-53-troubleshoot-nxdomain-responses)

Comment: コメントでなく、質問文を更新していただけますか。

Comment: ドメインを AWS 以外で取得したのであれば、対処方法は「ドメインがサードパーティに登録されている場合は、そのドメインのマニュアルで、ネームサーバーの更新手順を確認してください。」の方です。
whois の(レジストラ側の) Name Server を AWS のものに変更します。

Answer (score 1):

相変わらず何の操作を行ったのか具体性がなく読み取れません。

Route53において、**取得したドメインでEC2インスタンスに名前解決**までに必要な操作を並べておきます。

- EIP

  - アドレスを仮に 192.0.2.1 とします。
- Public HostedZone

  - **作成する際のホストゾーン名は 取得したドメイン example.com を指定する**
  - 作成すると Name Servers に複数（概ね4個）のサーバーが設定される
  - **Aレコードを作成し、EIPのアドレス 192.0.2.1 を設定する**

    - この設定が行われていない場合、接続時に host not found 等のエラーが発生する
- Amazon Register

  - 取得したドメインを仮に example.com とします。
  - **ドメインのネームサーバーにPublic HostedZoneのName Serversの4個を設定する**

    - この設定が行われていない場合、接続時に NXDOMAIN 等のエラーが発生する

---

以上のことから、期待通りの動作をしない原因は

- 接続確認しているドメインと取得したドメインが異なる
- 取得したドメインと作成したHostedZone名が異なる
- 作成したHostedZoneがpublicでない
- ドメインのネームサーバーに設定した値と作成したHostedZoneのName Serversの値が異なる

いずれかだとは思います。